# Debug Plotly Surface Title Not Updating

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

I have written the following simple code with a recurrent function:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='iframe_connected'
import math
%matplotlib inline
x=[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]
y=x
init=0
def surface(x,y,stop,time,ct):
    z=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    i=0
    for _ in x:
        for __ in y:
            try:
                a=math.sqrt(ct*time+_**2-__**2)
            except ValueError:
                a=0
            z[i].append(a)
        i+=1
    for _ in z:
        _=list(map(lambda x:round(x,2),_))
    z_2d=np.array(z).reshape(7,7)
    surf=go.Figure(
        layout=go.Layout(
            template='plotly_dark',
            title=dict(
                text='Surface after {} seconds'.format(time),
                xref='paper',
                pad_t=15
            )
        )
    )
    surf.add_trace(
        go.Surface(
            showlegend=False,
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z_2d,
            surfacecolor=z_2d,
            colorbar=dict(
                tickmode='auto',
                ticks='outside',
                nticks=6
            ),
            colorscale='Jet'
        )
    )
    pio.show(surf)
    time+=1
    if time<stop:
        surface(x,y,stop,time,ct)
    else:
        pass
surface(x,y,10,init,np.e)
```

The idea is that each surface that is printed the title should change as the variable `time` is changing `time+=1`. The recurssion prints correctly 10 surfaces but the titles are assigned randomly, I don't understand why, I even added at some point `print(time)` before and after I add `+1` and when printing the surfaces it correctly prints `1,2` then `2,3`, then `3,4`, etc. But the titles keep saying "after 0 seconds" even though it should say "3"; or "after 6 seconds" when it should say "5,6,7,8 respectively" to then suddenly change to "9" or whatever. Here some samples:
[image: surface for time=3]
[image: surface on time=6]

Please your help to point out what I am doing wrong, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is the timing between when `pio` creates the image as html and when it tries to show the image with `pio.show(surf)`.  When you use [`iframe_connected`](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/#builtin-renderers) plotly will:

> ...write figures out as standalone HTML files and then display iframe
>   elements that reference these HTML files...

and

> With the iframe renderers, the figure data are stored in the
>   individual HTML files...

So, if `pio.show(surf)` is called before the next one is ready then the previous html will end up being used.

To test this, first try adding a print statement right before `pio.show(surf)` to inspect your layout, and you should see that the title is being set properly.    Something like:

```py
    print(surf)
    pio.show(surf)
```

and you will see incrementing versions of:

```
...
'layout': {'template': '...', 'title': {'pad': {'t': 15}, 'text': 'Surface after 0 seconds', 'xref': 'paper'}}
...
```

Next add a delay to allow some time for plotly to generate the html:

```
    tm.sleep(5)
    pio.show(surf)
```

Note: you'll need to add `import time as tm` at the top.  Also, `time` is usually a bad name for a variable, but we can avoid the problem with `as tm`.

Comment: you are more than right, the problem was that I was not given the time to create the new html, adding a time of 3 gave me the perfect solution. Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate the time you took to check my question!